# Both Sims are not detected after update Lenovo A390 with the latest ROW firmware

Tags: rom, sim-unlocking, lenovo

I have format my Lenovo A390 and update to latest ROW firmware version A390_ROW_S316_130730.
Everything work fine but sim cards not detected. At down of the lock screen shows Invalid IMEI. In the status bar sim also not showing.

- Model number     :- Lenovo A390_Row
- Android version  :- 4.0.4
- Baseband version :- A390_MB_PCB_V1.0
- Build number     :- A390_ROW_S316_130730

IMEI are Unknown

Wifi also work fine. What should I do now. Please help

Comment: Head over to the dialer and type *#06# over it and see if it shows the IMEI number, if it shows the IMEI number then things are okay but if there's nothing showing over their means the problem is with the IMEI and the device needs to feed IMEI onto !

Comment: IMEI doesn't show with  *#06#. Both are Invalid. :/

Comment: Well, I have Google thinks out, and have spotted a post over [GSM Hosting](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f606/mt6572-6575-6577-6589-mtk-android-based-phone-imei-write-tool-1708731/) you can have a look over the post ! And see if that helps you out with the problem you are experiencing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself. Reason of the problem was Invalid IMEI number. What I did is set the valied IMEI for Sim.

Steps to Change IMEI Number of Your Android

- Write the following in your dialler – `*#7465625# or *#*#3646633#*#*`.
  (`*#*#3646633#*#*` this work for me)
- Click to Call pad or connectivity options. Find out **CDS information**
- and tap on it. Check out for Radio information. If
  you have dual SIM, there will be two options for you, select the one which you want to go with.
- Now to change IMEI number follow 
  AT +EGMR=1,7,”IMEI_1”

Replace IMEI_1 with your IMIE. For example : **AT+EGMR=1,7,”8600XXXXXXXXXXXX"**

- And click to send.

Changing IMEI number is illegal but it may help you to get your phone back. Make sure to use  "YOUR" phone IMIE number (15 digit code ) written in the backside of the phone (mostly Under the battery)

EDIT

For Sim 2 need this insert “AT +EGMR=1,**10**,"IMEI_2”

Comment: Only one sim working. Other sim shows Invalid IMEI

Comment: For Phone 2 need this insert “AT +EGMR=1,10,"IMEI_2”